# Copying a cell with a picture inside and pasting in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, image, copy-paste

I'm having an issue trying to paste a copied cell that has a picture inside. I'll put the code here so you guys can try to understand the situation. Everything in the code is working fine but this.

Thank you very much.

```
Do While shtPic.Cells(k, 1) <> Empty
    If shtPic.Cells(k, 1) = shtProforma.Cells(j, 2) Then
        shtPic.Cells(k, 3).Copy
        shtProforma.Cells(j, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Exit Do
    End If
    k = k + 1
Loop
```

The copying part is fine. It copies from the `shtPic` but it don't paste at `shtProforma`.

Comment: Activate your second sheet first, select destination cell and then paste. Make sure the picture doesn't exceed the cell's borders!

Comment: Start the macro recorder and then perform the task manually. Then you can inspect and/or change the generated code as required.  See: [Recording a Macro to Generate Code](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) and [Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: Which Error-Code do you get?
Are shtPic and shtProforma worksheets?

Can you show the whole code?

Comment: I don't get any error. It just don't paste the cell with the picture inside. I've run some tests with the same cell but with a word inside and it copies and paste normally. And yes, they are worksheets.